# How to remove line breaks from a file?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, bash, programming-languages

How to remove:

```
<p> (break line!!!)
text...
</p> (break line!!!)
```

from a file with regex?

I tried:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e "s/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g" {} \;
```

Comment: -1 for insisting on doing this with a regex rather than with a Real Parser

Answer (score 2):

This stuff can **really** blow up in your face so be careful; try it with test data in a test dir etc.

The `-0` switch will "turn off" the default record separator (`$/`) so you can do multiple lines at once. The `s` lets `.` match across newlines and the `+?` is to make it lazy up to the "TERRANO." Try this test on one of your files.

```
perl -0 -p -e 's/<p>.+?TERRANO[^<]*<\/p>//gs'
```

If that works, you can add it to your original.

```
find . -type f -exec perl -0 -pi -e "s/<p>.+?TERRANO[^<]*<\/p>//gs" {} \;
```

As mentioned in a comment, if the content *is* HTML, you should probably be using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do it.

First is to undef `$\`.
Then you match something like

`/\<p\>\nTERRANO.*\n\<\/p\>/`

which may depend upon whether or not you are using cr/lf's, or just lf's/

Second is to use a loop to concatenate the lines (plus whatever is in `$\`) and match that in one regex, including matching whatever is in `$\`.

Third would be to use File::Slurp.

Fourth is to use several regexes and a loop to match each line, and if all three are satisfied, do your substitution.

Comment: Thank you! When I want to match all text between <p> tags, then what is the solution?

Comment: @hulla, you'd probably want to use an XML/HTML parser

Comment: No I don't want. The text is in simple text files.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the Unix text editor ed to remove a range of lines with regex:

```
str='
BEFORE MULTILINE PATTERN 1
<p> (break line!!!)
text...
</p> (break line!!!)
AFTER MULTILINE PATTERN 1
BEFORE MULTILINE PATTERN 2 
<p> (break line!!!)
text...
</p> (break line!!!)
AFTER MULTILINE PATTERN 2
'

# for in-place file editing use "ed -s file" and replace ",p" with "w"
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed

cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' -e '/^ *#/d' | ed -s <(echo "$str")
  H
  # only remove the first match
  #/<p>/,/<\/p>/d
  # remove all matches
  g/<p>/+0,/<\/p>/+0d
  ,p
  q
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use multi-line regexp:

```
s/regexp/replacement/m
```

See [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=18001)

Comment: No, the `m` modifier will only let `^` match the start of the line (instead of the start of the input), and will let `$` match the end of a line (instead of the end of the input).

Comment: What you actually want is the `s` modifier, which treats the entire string as a single line.